# [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have this data and computed method is also there

```js
data(){
    return {
        pdf_path:'',
        medical: {
            name: '',
            designation: '',
            account_no: '',
            staff_no: '',
        },
     }
},

computed:{ 
    getFilePath: function () {  
        if(this.pdf_path!=""){
            return '../../../../storage/' + this.pdf_path + '?t=' + new Date().getTime();
        }
    }
},

async mounted(){
    const header = {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.getLoginUserData,
    };
    await axios.get('/api/backend/users',{headers:header}).then((responseUser) => {
        this.medical.name = responseUser.data.name;
        this.medical.account_no = responseUser.data.account_no;
        this.medical.staff_no = responseUser.data.userUniqueId;
        this.medical.designation = responseUser.data.role_id;
        return axios.get(`/api/backend/dependent-list/${this.userId}`,{headers:header}); 
    });
},
```

In the template i'm using the computed property:

```html
<iframe :src="`${getFilePath}`" width="100%" height="350px" type="application/pdf"></iframe>
```

but if i use computed property then i get error in console

> [Vue warn]: Error in callback for watcher "medical.name": "TypeError:
> Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'name' in null"

Should i have to initialize all variable in computed method?

Comment: This doesn't differ much from previous question. getFilePath isn't related to medical, and `medical` isn't null and can't cause this error. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . If you're not sure the code reproduces it, try to reproduce it from scratch in a way in which other users will be able to run it. I'm quite sure you won't be able to do this with currently posted code, and the problem is something else that you didn't show

Comment: The only possibility I see is that iframe tries to load a page from wrong url and initializes another copy of the app that goes wrong and causes this error. Make sure that iframe loads a correct page. `../../../../storage/` looks fishy and error-prone.